# Is there a real-analytic monotone function $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which vanishes at infinity, but whose derivative admits no limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, monotone-functions

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called real-analytic if for each $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a neighbourhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is given by a convergent power series centred at $x_0$.

> Problem: Is there a real-analytic monotone function $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which vanishes at infinity, but whose derivative admits no limit as $x \to \infty$?

We can note some weaker, but related, results. The (non-monotone) function $f(x)=x^{-1} \sin x^2$ is a real-analytic function on $(0, +\infty)$ and has the property that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0$ but $\lim_{x \to + \infty} f'(x)$ fails to exist. It's not difficult to construct monotone examples *if* real-analyticity is weakened to merely being infinitely differentiable. The basic construction is straightforward. For each integer $n \geq 2$, and on each interval $[n, n+1-1/n^3]$, set $f(x)=1/n$, and on intervals $[ n+1-1/n^3, n+1]$ the function is linear, and decreasing from $\frac{1}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}$. This function is piecewise linear, and not smooth at the transition points, but it's trivial to smoothen this construction by utilizing appropriate variants of $\exp(1/x)$, rather than a linear interpolation. By the mean value theorem, we have that $\sup_{x \in [n+1-1/n^3, n+1]} |f'(x)| \geq \left|\frac{\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}\right|=\frac{n^3}{n(n+1)} \xrightarrow{n \to + \infty} + \infty$ hence $\lim f'(x)$ fails to exist.

However, I don't think one can use these ideas to obtain a real-analytic monotone function with the desired properties, since there's no real-analytic "transition" functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we need is a real-analytic non-negative and integrable $g$ that has no limit at $+\infty$. Then
$$f(x) = \int_x^{+\infty} g(t)\,dt$$
fits the bill.

Consider
$$g(x) = \biggl(\frac{2 + \cos x}{3}\biggr)^{6 x^5}\,.$$

It is evident that $g$ is strictly positive, real-analytic on $(0,+\infty)$, and has no limit as $x \to +\infty$. It remains to see that $g$ is integrable. For a positive integer $n$, consider the interval of length $\pi$ with midpoint $n\pi$. In this interval, for $\lvert x - n\pi\rvert \geqslant \frac{1}{n^2}$ we have
$$\lvert \cos x\rvert \leqslant \cos \bigl(n^{-2}\bigr) \leqslant 1 - \frac{1}{2n^4} + \frac{1}{24n^8} \leqslant 1 - \frac{1}{3n^4}$$
by Taylor expansion, and hence (using $\bigl(n - \frac{1}{2}\bigr)\pi > \frac{3}{2}n$)
$$g(x) \leqslant \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{9n^4}\biggr)^{9n^5} \leqslant \exp \bigl(-n\bigr)\,.$$
Hence the integral of $g$ over that interval is bounded by
$$\frac{2}{n^2} + \pi\cdot e^{-n}\,,$$
which is a summable sequence.

Comment: Don't understand the inequality of cosx. I know that inequality is 1-cosx<=x^2/2.

Comment: Right, that's a mistake, but a small reduction of the constants makes it right. Editing.

Comment: Yes! Finally understood. You use inequalities in a great way.

Comment: I don't think your $g$ is real analytic. Looks like there's trouble at the zeros of this function. Take $\pi/2$ for example. Then $g(x)$ is behaving like $|x-\pi/2|^{6+2(\pi/2)^5}$ near $\pi/2.$ That's not a zero of positive integer order.

Comment: Oops, @zhw., indeed. We need to make it strictly positive.

Comment: You might try $$\left ( \frac{2+\cos x}{3} \right)^{x^5}$$ instead.

Comment: Nice idea @zhw., thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(x):=e^{-k^4x^2}$ has
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\>dx={\sqrt{\pi}\over k^2}\ .$$
The function
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\exp\bigl(-k^4(x-k)^2\bigr)>0\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)$$
is then real analytic, and so is
$$F(x):=\int_x^\infty f(t)\>dt\ .$$
This $F$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$. As 
$$F'(x)=-f(x)<-1\qquad(x\in{\mathbb N})$$
we have an example of the desired kind.